# Writing a numpy matrix to a file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file-io, matplotlib

I am trying to write a numpy array to a file. But it deos not work. My problem follows.

I am trying to get the RGB pixel values of a picture using `matplotlib.image` and save the values obtained from my program to some file for future use.

The values are returned in the form of an array, which I tried to write to a text file using the following code. But the file does not open. Nor does it show an error message.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img=mpimg.imread('kitten5.jpeg')
print(img)

f=open('kitten.dat','w')
f.write(img)
f.close()

imgplot=plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Can someone help? It is not mandatory that the data has to be saved to a text file alone. Other suggestions are equally welcome.

Comment: Do you actually need a formated txt file? Or you could have a binary file, which usually is much more efficient when dealing with images?

Comment: Yes a binary file will do. And it will be also helpful to know about a formatted txt file. But for my present purpose, please do guide me on binary files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving the image into a numpy binary file, you may want to use:

```
np.save('outputfile', img)
```

The nice thing about np.save is that you can recover your numpy objects later on with:

```
np.load('outputfile.npy')
```

and you don't need to care about the shape, dtype, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. Any tips about formatted txt file?

Comment: Just use np.savetxt('output.txt', img, fmt='%.3f'). But I don't recommend this for big images. Of course, the value of fmt will depend on the desired format.

Comment: But adding this line shows this message: `TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray`

Comment: Oh, I see. This is because your matrix has different channels. You can save a single txt file for every channel: np.savetxt('output_r.txt', img[:,:,0], fmt='%.3f'), np.savetxt('output_g.txt', img[:,:,1], fmt='%.3f'), np.savetxt('output_b.txt', img[:,:,2], fmt='%.3f'), and eventually an alpha channel.

Comment: This issue came up in another question.  `savetxt` is for 2d arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It works perfectly well now. @Alejandro